# What is the general practice to redirect users back to their shopping cart after a certain criteria is matched

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am building an online course website with Wordpress + Buddyboss + Woocommerce + Learndash. Due to our policy, all users are required to complete their profile before they can place an order. I was able to achieve this with the following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form',function(){
  if (is_user_logged_in()){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( bpprocn_has_incomplete_profile($user->id) ) { //check if profile is completed
      if (wp_redirect(bp_core_get_user_domain( $user->id ) . bp_get_profile_slug() . '/edit/group/2')) exit; //redirect user to profile edit page
    }
  }
});
```

Now, after users finish editing their profile and click "save", I need to redirect them back to their cart. I was able to build a custom action that triggers after the "save profile" button is rendered and use this action to show a link next to the "save profile" button.

```
add_action('wsk_add_continue_shop_button',function(){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() && !bpprocn_has_incomplete_profile($user->id)) echo '<a class="uk-button" href="/cart">continue shopping</a>';  // if user's cart is not empty and profile is completed, show the "continue shopping" link.
  });
```

This is of course not the best solution because it relies on users to click the link, and if some users overlook the newly added link, their user experience will be very bad. So I definitely need to automatically redirect users back to their cart once they complete their profile and click "save profile".

I can't simply do `wp_redirect()` in the above code, because that would redirect those users who have completed their profile, have something in their cart and get to the profile editing page, maening these users will never see the profile editing page unless they clear their cart.

My knowledge of PHP and Wordpress is quite limited, so I need some advice here. One thing I can think of is to check if `$_POST` is empty, if it is not empty then it probably means the user just submit some changes or new infos of their profile, and in these cases I can do `wp_redirect`. But is this approach reliable? If a user just wants to edit his profile and he has something in the cart, he will be redirected too, which is unwanted.

Another question I can think of is, when I do the first redirection ( when users try to place an order, redirect them to their profile editting page if their profile is incompleted ), is there a way to mark this user as "This user has just tried to place an order and been redirected" so he can be distinguished from those users who didn't try to place an order and just want to edit their profile? It seems to me to do this I need to tap into session data, but I have close to zero knowledge about session manipulation... Does wordpress has anything helpful in this aspect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the the original Wordpress Event - profile_update.
It fires directly after an existing user is updated.

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'checkUserUpdate', 10, 1 );
 
function checkUserUpdate( $user_id ) {
  // check if your user profile is complete and your WC
  // cart is not empty and redirect him to the cart
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is helpful and partly solve my problem. However, if a user just wanted to edit his profile and he happens to have something in this cart, he will be redirected too. So the question is, how do I distinguish users who just want to edit their profile and users who was required to complete their profile when trying to place an order?

Comment: @shenkwen - You could check the referrer on the userprofil-editing-page by
`$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; `
and if the refferer was the shopping cart site you can set a flag in the wordpress session

`$wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
$wp_session['userCameFromCart'] = true;`

Then the event fires and you function will be executed you could check the flag and if it´s true you can redirect this user back to the  card. And maybe you should unset the flag before redirecting. 
If the flag was not set or false - just do nothing and exit the function by return.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Again, it is very helpful. I've been spending time on learning how to use cookie to solve this problem. Do you think cookie is a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @shenkwen If you use cookies or html5 local.storage, you should be aware that you store this info on the user's browser. If you then need them in PHP, you have to send them to the server somehow, e.g. through an Ajax call. Therefore I think that the way over the session is easier.

Comment: I've thought of a way to do this and post another answer. Please take a look when you get a chance, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've thought of a way to solve this. It seems working, need more test though.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form',function(){
  if (is_user_logged_in()){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( bpprocn_has_incomplete_profile($user->id) ) { //check if profile is completed
      if (wp_redirect(bp_core_get_user_domain( $user->id ) . bp_get_profile_slug() . '/edit/group/2?redirected=wsk_checkout')) exit; //redirect user to profile edit page with a GET parameter
    }
  }
});
```

If user tries to checkout without a completed profile, they will get redirected to the profile editing page with a GET parameter. On this page, if they complete their profile and save changes, a "profile_update" action will trigger and the profile editing page reloads with a `HTTP_REFERER` that contains the previously set GET parameter:

```
add_action('profile_update',function(){
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() && !bpprocn_has_incomplete_profile($user->id) && str_contains($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'wsk_checkout')) { 
      wp_redirect('/checkout');
      exit;
    }
  });
```

The above code checks if the user's cart is not empty and his profile is completed and the GET parameter exists in `HTTP_REFERER`, if yes, redirect them back to checkout page.

This way, users simply trying to update their profile and happen to have something in the cart won't get redirected to the checkout page because they won't have the GET parameter.